# MapViewController displays view for current location always

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios5, ios6

I Have written the below code for example:

But i an directed to always to my current location.  How can i solve this issue ?

```
 MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];

CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

annotationCoord.latitude = 47.640071;
annotationCoord.longitude = -122.129598;

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
annotationPoint.title = @"Microsoft";
annotationPoint.subtitle = @"Microsoft's headquarters";
[mvc.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

NOTE:

MapViewcontroller.h

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on below of your code

```
 MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotationCoord, 200, 200)];
[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

May be help full.. Cheers ...

Comment: Joge, no , it does not. same result ;(

Comment: MapViewController, Is this subclass of MKMapView ?

Comment: joge, i have edited the question and kept MapViewController declaration/definiton.

Comment: in MapViewController you can see , also write down code of  Userlocation . Comment this line " self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;" and try again

Comment: I have commented the line, but still shows the my place, but blue button is invisbile now. i dont understand 'User location code'. i have not written any code than mentioned in the question?. did i miss something?. you mean delegete method?

Comment: try this example may be helpfull for you .. http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-beginners/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57991/discussion-between-joge-and-whoami).